Is there a way to retrieve the stories of Deevi-La and Quaza-Kar from a deactivated Deviantart account?
A number of years ago, there were some stories on Deviantart starring a jungle woman named Deevi-La and Quaza-Kar, a jungle man who would become her husband.
Here is what I remember about those stories.
Setting

The setting is another world inside the Earth in the 1800s. I believe people call this the Hollow Earth.
At the beginning of each story, a professor from England talks about how he discovered this world and met Deevi-La. It took time, but he managed to gain her trust and learn her language.
Deevi is the first-person narrator of these stories, and the professor is the one who recorded them in English.
The stories themselves seem to be a lot like the ones you would find in the pulps. It might have "Tarzan" by Edgar Rice Burroughs as an influence.

Protagonists

Deevi is the daughter of a captured Axe Woman (the equivalent of an Amazon warrior in these stories) and a warrior. It seems that her father was quite an abusive man.
Deevi is a voluptuous light-skinned woman with blonde hair and blue eyes. She is also quite strong, and knows hand-to-hand combat techniques, such as armbars. She also knows Axe Women combat techniques, which she probably learned from her mother.
In the tribe, Deevi had to choose between becoming a Woman of the Skin and Woman of the Flesh. A Woman of the Skin is a female warrior and hunter who wears that skin of the animal that she killed in her coming of age ritual as clothing. A Woman of the Flesh is a woman who has sex with men.
The tribe treats Deevi as an outcast and calls her "Deevi the Cursed". She has always been a fighter, so she chose to become a Woman of the Skin to have control over her life.
Despite her skills, Deevi is always at a disadvantage in her fights. One fight started with two women ambushing her. Other fights showed her fighting men who are obviously a lot bigger and stronger than her. In some fights, she was also pregnant.
Quaza is a large, muscular light-skinned man with blond hair and blue eyes. He is as strong as they come and seems to be extremely hard to beat in close-quarters combat. However, he does reveal at one point that he cannot see long distances. In other words, he is near-sighted and needs a pair of glasses. Personally, I think the writer modelled him after Tarzan.
Quaza is usually quite a nice guy, but he proves to be quite deadly when enraged. In particular, he has a berserker rage that makes him stronger and faster.

First Story

The first story focuses on Deevi meeting Quaza for the first time as they both undergo coming of age rituals.
These rituals entail hunting a dangerous animal, killing it, skinning it, and wearing its skin as clothing.
To find these animals, Deevi and Quaza have to go into a jungle area and explore some parts of their world.
Deevi eventually kills the setting's equivalent of a raptor. Quaza eventually kills the setting's equivalent of a gorilla.
Once they get the skins and return to their tribe, they also undergo a marriage ritual.
This ritual requires Deevi and two Women of the Flesh to fight Quaza with all their might. As Deevi expected, Quaza easily defeats and has sex with all three of them.
Quaza announces that while he will take all three women as his wives, he will make Deevi his first and primary wife. The tribe is shocked and appalled by him granting her such a privilege. Deevi is overjoyed that Quaza would do this for her and knows that she will love him for the rest of her life.

Second Story

The second story starts off with the tribe fighting a war against a tribe of Sea People, who are dark-skinned people with a sea theme. Deevi manages to kill some Sea People, and captures a strong Sea Woman named Xai.
Quaza wants to add some strong women to his harem. That is, he wants women who can fight him so he can subdue them and have sex. The two Women of the Flesh are no warriors and Xai made it clear that she would rather die before having sex with him.
Since none of the women in the tribe can satisfy his needs, Quaza seeks permission from the chief to go to the land of the Axe Women. The chief gives him permission on the condition that he bring his brother with him so that he can complete his coming of age ritual.
Quaza's brother is quite disagreeable and has a snake motif.
Deevi, Quaza, his brother and Xai go on a journey to the land of the Axe Women. The brother tries to hunt and kill a sea monster but fails miserably.
The four of them come to a land that is ruled by a corrupt and obese man. Deevi finds an Axe Woman who is used as a sex slave. They try to strike a bargain with the ruler to set the Axe Woman free, but the ruler ends up betraying them by delivering the Axe Woman's head to them as they leave.
Moving on, they eventually find the Axe Women. Quaza takes on one of them, but his brother betrays them by throwing a spear into Quaza's back, throwing Xai off a cliff (she survives this), and leaving Deevi with the Axe Women as he runs back to his tribe. Clearly, Quaza's relationship with his brother is like that of Cain and Abel.
Along the way, Deevi and Xai grow to love each other. As it turns out, Xai is only attracted to women, which explains a lot. Deevi finds it in herself to love Xai as a person. Quaza told her earlier on that he thinks Xai is a lot like her, and he was right. Deevi even explains to Xai that Quaza knows what is between them and that they have his blessing.
Deevi meets the Queen of the Axe Women, who turns out to be her mother's sister. The Queen makes an offer for Deevi to join her, but Deevi decides to remain loyal to Quaza. As a result, the Queen makes her own niece into a slave.
The Queen puts Quaza through three challenges. The first challenge involves twelve Axe Women trying to knock him off a log. The second challenge involves the twelve women trying to beat Quaza in hand-to-hand combat. The third challenge involves a tug of war between the twelve women and Quaza. Quaza manages to win all three challenges, and it becomes clear that two of the twelve Axe Women can hardly wait to join Quaza's harem. Quaza refers to those two Axe Women as the daughters of Fay. All he has to do afterwards is defeat the Queen in combat and have sex with her. In this way, his freedom will be assured.
Unfortunately, the Queen has no intention of having sex with Quaza or being humiliated by any man. She plans to have Quaza fight the twelve Axe Women, the Queen's two bodyguards and the Queen herself at the same time. Once they defeat him, they will sacrifice him to male Fire God that they worship by throwing him into a lava pit. Quaza is still recovering from the spear wound in his back, and even he reluctantly admits that he can't defeat 15 Axe Women at once in his condition.
Having warned them of the Queen's plot, the daughters of Fay try to help him, Deevi and Xai escape. However, they run into an ambush and an arrow hits Xai in the throat, killing her in the process. She has enough time to thank Deevi for letting her love her before she dies.
The Axe Women capture Deevi and force her to witness the Queen and her cohorts cut off Xai's head and throw it into the lava pit. Deevi mourns her death and warns the Queen that the only reason men have not rightfully conquered the Axe Women is because of the natural barriers surrounding their fortress.
The Queen shrugs off the warning and reveals that she knows that Deevi is pregnant. She intends to let Deevi give birth to the child so that she can take him/her under her wing. This disturbs the Axe Women because the Queen is breaking centuries of tradition. She also states that she intends to have the child watch as Deevi is sacrificed to the Fire God. She acknowledges that infants don't remember the first few years of their lives…but she doesn't believe it to be the case.
There are more sex scenes in the second story than in the first, such as those between Deevi and Quaza, Deevi and Xai, and Quaza and the two Axe Women.
Unfortunately, this story ends in a cliffhanger. It seems that the writer was going to continue it, but bad things came up and got in the way.

Third Story

Deevi goes to upper world to find a famed jungle woman. This jungle woman is none other than Sheena, Queen of the Jungle. For the record, Sheena is a public domain character who has had many versions over the years. This version has a female mate whose name might be Keema.
Surprising Sheena, Deevi challenges her to a fight.
It is a tough fight, but Deevi manages to defeat her.
Keema begs Deevi to take her with her, but Deevi refuses, because she feels that Keema would not be strong enough to survive in her world.
The story ends with Sheena as a member of Quaza's harem. Quaza defeats her in combat and has sex with her.
Interestingly, Deevi has given birth to her child. It is a girl, and she has named her Xai.
In addition, the daughters of Fay, and the two Women of the Flesh and their children are absent. Perhaps they had died.

Now, I don't know this for sure, but I think the user who wrote these stories was also behind the Barbarian Babes website, which has video games such as "Ninjazon".
So far, I have found only one Deviantart pic featuring Deevi-La. I found it in an archive listing the favourite pics of a Deviantart user named eyeteeth. The title of the pic is "Deevi-La-Slaughters-the-Slave-Takers-350144977.jpe". I remember that there were other pics featuring Deevi-La and Quaza-Kar, but I have had no luck finding them so far.
I hope someone can help me find a way to retrieve these stories.

Possibly you could find it on the Wayback Machine, though I don't know if that's recovered from the hack on it yet.

It's back in a read-only format.
